# countdown.js - Keith Wood - IE8 (js fiddle provided)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I've implemented Keith Wood's countdown.js to iterate over a set of special offers and provide a countdown.

onExpiry it fires a function that add's a class to then overlay an 'expired' image and overlay on the offer.

It's working perfectly in all browsers (so far) bar IE8 and I can't for the life of my figure out why.

IE8 is throwing a script error but it's not really helping me much..

"Object doesn't support this property or method"..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // loop over each offer
    //var currentOffer;
    $('.df-offer').each(function(){
        currentOffer = $(this);
        //get and set the height of the expired overlay incase the content pushes it passed the design
        offerHeight = $(this).height();
        offerWidth = $(this).width();
        $('.df-special-offer-overlay').height(offerHeight);
        $('.df-special-offer-overlay').width(offerWidth);
        //coundown timer for each offer
        //create tne offer end date object from the string in the markup
        stringDate = $('.end-date', this).text().split("/");
        offerEnd = new Date(stringDate[2], stringDate[1] - 1, stringDate[0]);
        $('.timer', currentOffer).countdown({until: offerEnd, compact: true, alwaysExpire:true, onExpiry: function(){expireOffer(currentOffer);}});  
    });
        function expireOffer(offer){
        offer.addClass('expired');
        //remove the href value incase someone tries to get clever and inspects the page     for the offer URL.
        // leaves the attribute in place so the page still validates
        $('a.df-button', offer ).attr('href','#');
    };
});
```

Fiddle provided:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZUTL6/13/

Comment: anybody? :( "Object doesn't support this property or method" is the main error IE8 is throwing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might need to update jquery.plugin.js

See
[Object doesn't support this property or method IE8 and Countdown.js Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147303/object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-ie8-and-countdown-js-plugin)
And
https://github.com/kbwood/countdown/issues/41