# Object doesn't support this property or method IE8 and Countdown.js Plugin

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

Error in IE8:  Object expected

code:

```
return base[name].apply(this, args);
```

Another error in IE8 (separate script): Object doesn't support this property or method

```
$('.timer', currentOffer).countdown({until: offerEnd, serverSync: serverTime, compact: true, alwaysExpire:true, onExpiry: function(){expireOffer(currentOffer);}
});
```

Been banging head against wall for a while now on this one.

If you'd like to see a JS fiddle that has all the code and various plugins etc then: http://jsfiddle.net/ZUTL6/13/

Works fine in everything > IE8

Any help muchly appreciated!

Comment: Any luck on this issue? I have a couple of hours now trying to find a solution. jQuery Countdown has a dependency on a "jquery.plugin.js" file that has this error. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is called having luck. Keith uploaded a fix for this 3 hours ago: https://github.com/kbwood/countdown/issues/41

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The owner of the plugin just added a fix for this 3 hours ago:
https://github.com/kbwood/countdown/issues/41

Just need to downloaded the latest version of jquery.plugin.js